# How to sort DataGridTextColumn by displayed, converted value, not bound source property value?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

How to sort WPF DataGridTextColumn by displayed, converted value, not bound source property value? Now it's sorted by integer value in row viewmodel, not displayed text returned by Converter. I use MVVM.

Here is an example by request. This however is general question. I could put MmsClass.Name in class representing the row. But I need proper sorting everywhere, not only here.

Class for a row:

```
public class MaintenanceDataItem
{
    public MaintenanceDataItem(int classId, Type objectType, object value, IEnumerable<MmsData> rows)
    {
        ClassId = classId;
        TypeOfObject = objectType;
        Value = value;
        ObjectIds = new List<int>();
        MmsDataRows = rows;
    }

    public int ClassId { get; private set; }
    // rest of the properrties omitted
}
```

converter:

```
public class MmsClassToNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MmsClass mmsClass;
        if (MmsClasses.Instance.TryGetValue((int) value, out mmsClass))
        {
            return mmsClass.Name;
        }
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

column in xaml:

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MmsStrCondClass}" Binding="{Binding ClassId, Converter={StaticResource mmsclasstonameconverter}}" Width="*">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
                        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap" />
                        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

I really thought that default sorting would be displayed value. Using converters makes not so much sense for datagridcolumn if this is not easily solved.

Comment: share some code to understand your issue better...

Comment: thanks for interest. my question was general. that's why I omitted the code. i added one piece of code nevertheless.

Comment: Have you tried setting `SortMemberPath` to the `Text` property of your column? I'm not sure, if you could set a Binding like `<DataGridTextColumn  SortMemberPath="{Binding Path=Text}" ... />`. Maybe you need to set a RelativeSource (just play around with this).

Comment: DataGridTextColumn has no Text. it has to be found in some other way. find child that is textblock and it's Text.

Comment: i tried this without success:                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MmsStrCondClass}" Binding="{Binding ClassId, Converter={StaticResource mmsclasstonameconverter}}" 
                                    SortMemberPath="{Binding Path=Binding, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                                    Width="*">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not a trivial task. As @Maverik correctly pointed out, `DataGrid` sorts on the underlying data, not what a converter spits out. To do this, you'll need to `Sort` yourself. Start by creating a class with a property to use your custom sorters, and another to define the sorter to use on a given column:

```
    public static ICustomSorter GetCustomSorter(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICustomSorter)obj.GetValue(CustomSorterProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCustomSorter(DependencyObject obj, ICustomSorter value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CustomSorterProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CustomSorter.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomSorterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CustomSorter", typeof(ICustomSorter), typeof(CustomSortBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static bool GetAllowCustomSort(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AllowCustomSortProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAllowCustomSort(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AllowCustomSortProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for AllowCustomSort.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowCustomSortProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AllowCustomSort", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomSortBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, AllowCustomSortChanged));
```

`ICustomSorter` is a very simple interface:

```
public interface ICustomSorter : IComparer
{
    ListSortDirection SortDirection { get; set; }

    string SortMemberPath { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need to implement the custom sort from "AllowCustomSort":

```
    private static void AllowCustomSortChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid control = d as DataGrid;
        {
            var oldAllow = (bool)e.OldValue;
            var newAllow = (bool)e.NewValue;

            if (!oldAllow && newAllow)
            {
                control.Sorting += HandleCustomSorting;
            }
            else
            {
                control.Sorting -= HandleCustomSorting;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void HandleCustomSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if we should even be using custom sorting
        DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid != null && GetAllowCustomSort(dataGrid))
        {
            //Make sure we have a source we can sort
            ListCollectionView itemsSource = dataGrid.ItemsSource as ListCollectionView;
            if (itemsSource != null)
            {
                ICustomSorter columnSorter = GetCustomSorter(e.Column);

                //Only do our own sort if a sorter was defined
                if (columnSorter != null)
                {
                    ListSortDirection nextSortDirection = e.Column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ?
                                                          ListSortDirection.Descending :
                                                          ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                    e.Column.SortDirection = columnSorter.SortDirection = nextSortDirection;
                    columnSorter.SortMemberPath = e.Column.SortMemberPath;
                    itemsSource.CustomSort = columnSorter;

                    //We've handled the sort, don't let the DataGrid mess with us
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is just wiring up the `Sorting` event and then handling it by calling the provided `ICustomSorter` to sort the collection.

In your XAML, you create an instance of an implemented `ICustomSorter` and use the attached properties like so:

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Column1, Converter={StaticResource Column1Converter}}" IsReadOnly="True"
                                util:CustomSortBehavior.CustomSorter="{StaticResource Column1Comparer}"/>
```

Its painful, and you have to custom sort all your converted values, but it does allow you to do this in a `DataGrid`.

Comment: This has dataGrid.ItemsSource as a type ListCollectionView. However, my code uses List. Is it required to bind to a ListCollectionView, or is that just the simplest solution?

Comment: @BenJaguarMarshall A list collection view is just the view's view into a list.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you'd want to look into CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions.

Here's an example of what this may look like:

#### XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Fruits" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindowViewModel.Fruits}}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <ComponentModel:SortDescription Direction="Ascending" PropertyName="Length"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Fruits}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fruit Name" Binding="{Binding}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name Length" Binding="{Binding Length}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

where MainWindowViewModel.Fruits is simply defined as: `public static string[] Fruits { get; } = {"Apples", "Bananas", "Grapes", "Oranges", "Kiwis"};`

#### Result

This automatically generates:

[image: Sorted Data Screenshot]

Unfortunately this method will only work with viewmodel values and if you're using converters, you'd instead want to expose those values as viewmodel properties instead and then feed them into a SortDescriptions. To my limited knowledge DataGrid doesn't support this scenario even in user sort mode.

If you'd like to discuss this, please feel free to drop in our [#wpf room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf#) and grab any of the room owners and they'll be able to help if I'm not there already.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don't understand what any of this has to do with my question. this uses the property, not converted displayed value, right?

Comment: this also sets the ascending sort for lenght when window is opened. i just want to define how the sorting should work (by displayed value), not to set the sort.

Comment: the point was to show you CollectionViewSource + SortDescriptions. Not say you hard code it like I've shown in sample.

Re: your question of converted value, I've answered it. The short answer is it's not possible.

Comment: I've also answered the *how it should work* : it needs to be exposed via viewmodel conversion.. not via converters. If you're convinced this is not the answer, I'm happy to retract the answer.

Comment: i knew how collectionviewsource + sortdescriptions work. i use them all the time. i really can't believe it's not possible. why on earth somebody even wants to sort something else than displayed value?

Comment: @matti I agree with Maverick that the conversion should take place in the _View_-_Model_. It's the bound collection that's at the base of (out of the box) sorting, you could re-order the items yourself, but clicking the header afterwards would still apply sorting on the non converted values.

Comment: @matti *why on earth somebody even wants to sort something else than displayed value?* **Displayed Values** isn't the issue. The issue is you're doing view only conversion that data in binding isn't aware of. It makes perfect sense if you think about it. DataBinding is operating on ViewModel that isn't aware of any conversions thus DataGrid doesn't know how to sort converted values either. I find converters to be a crutch anyway and viewmodel conversions are far more efficient especially once you drive them off reactive collections

Comment: i think it totally different. my viewmodel doesn't need to know about displayed values. viewmodel handles values like 0,1,2 and view converts them to displayed values depending on language chosen. sorting is also done in view when user clicks the datagrid-header. i have always thought that mvvm relies heavily on converters so that viewmodel-irrelevant data is not needed there to "litter" the class and/or duplicate the data. i'm baffled that this is not the case. in my opinion that is far more elegant.

Comment: now i need to create new class that can be used ONLY on this DataGrid. i hoped to use general purpose classes that converters fetcch needed data- some of the data will be also duplicated because there will be properties for the data and it's representation.

Comment: @Maverik: I have used CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions when I need to set default sorting for one column. But my general case is that all 6 columns must be sortable. Can I use and why should I use CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions instead of just set column's SortMemberPath?

Comment: well there's another approach that's been mentioned in our #WPF room. You should see another answer soon. If not, you may want to come over to our room and nudge Bradley (or just read the transcript between myself and him)... As for why use SortDescriptions over SetMemberPath: I personally use collectionviewsource as one stop control for grouping & sorting regardless of the fact whether the displaying control supports SortMemberPath or not (they generally dont as you probably know). Also, SortDescriptions lets me do multi-sort that I'm not aware you can do with SortMemberPath.

Comment: @matti _My viewmodel doesn't need to know about displayed values._ 

I disagree, as the model holds our abstractions, the viewmodel needs to implement them and keep track of state. While the view should be kept _as dumb as possible_, merely representing viewmodel state.

That's why sorting can be done from the view, it's just representation. But the values used for sorting should come from the viewmodel. As for XAML Converters, I think of 'em in the sense of boolToVis, not for fetching data from dictionaries.

Comment: thanks Maverik and @bab7lon. i really thought this completely other way around. i'm gonna have very different approach from now on. i.e. have viewmodel to have more properties if needed even if i hate it. it just makes everything so much easier.

Comment: You're welcome matti and I completely agree with bab7lon's comment above as well. I know the feeling of having excessive properties on viewmodel but think of it this way, your view is much less cluttered now and you've got much more powerful conversions at your disposal without the need to shuttle data.

Answer (score 0):

Super simple working solution:

1. listen to DataGrid's Sorting event
2. when event is fired, verify the column
3. sort the list however you like
4. put the sorted new collection back to DataGrid's ItemsSource
5. flag event handled so basic sort will not be applied

example:

cs

```
        /// <summary>
        /// catch DataGrid's sorting event and 
        /// sort AllRows by employee, than by planit order
        /// </summary>
        private void MainDataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.Header is string header && header.Equals(Properties.Resources.EmployeeName))
            {
                // AllRows is a property binded to my DataGrid's ItemsSource
                AllRows = programaItems.ToList().OrderBy(item => item.SelectedWorkOrder.WorkOrderResource.EmployeeName).ThenBy(item => item.SelectedWorkOrder.WorkOrderResource.PlanitSetupOrder);
                // flag event handled
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

xaml

```
<DataGrid ... Sorting="MainDataGrid_Sorting">
    <DataGrid.Columns...
```